# How to get the ODOO navbar to display from right to left

Tags: html, css, styles, odoo

Putting Dir="rtl" in the body or direction=rtl in the web.assets_backend changes the direction correctly for all RTL elements under ODOO 10, EXCEPT for the top navigation bar.

There seems to be code for the navigation bar in webclient_templates.xml where it creates the navbar from a list of li elements. What can I do so this list is displayed from right to left, instead of the way it is now.

See http://snag.gy/sk2rYh.jpg Notice the inner parts of ODOO have changed correctly but not the navbar.